# Is it possible to dynamically add chart type in the extends: property, based on props from parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a vue chartjs component which imports the whole vue-chartjs library. My idea is, is it possible to somehow pass the type of the chart which I want and add it to the 'extends: VueCharts.charttype?.' In the example I provide it extends the VueCharts.Line, I need this property to be dynamically interpolated, passed from props. Is it possible this charttype to come from a parent props dynamically and how?

```
<script>
import { VueCharts } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: VueCharts.Line,
  props: ["chartdata", "options"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since extends the same as mixins, you need to pass a dynamic mixin, in order to do that you need two components, imagine we have component ChartWrapper :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ chartType }}</div>
    <chart :chart-data="datacollection"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from "./Chart";
import { VueCharts, mixins } from "vue-chartjs";
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;
export default {
  name: "ChartWrapper",
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  props: {
    chartType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datacollection: {
        labels: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
          },
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getRandomInt() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (this.chartType) {
      Chart.mixins = [reactiveProp,VueCharts[this.chartType]];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this component takes chartType as a prop, and I import all charts as VueCharts in top of the script **==> 1**

second component:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["options"],
  mounted() {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

the second component just has options props, and renderChart function invoked.
**==> 2**

**What is happening?**

the ChartWrapper component receives the chart type by chartType prop, in the **created** hook, if chartType  exist, assign the chart(resolved by VueCharts[this.chartType]) to Chart component as a mixin in addition to reactiveProp,
I also pass the chart data to Chart component.

in the end, call the ChartWrapper component:

```
<ChartWrapper chartType="Bar"/>
```

Live example on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-w9r8k

Comment: thanks buddy! It solved my problem! I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose for the option to just extend the Line chart and update the config of the chart with the chart type you want and give it an update so it changes type.

```js
<script>
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default {
  extends: Line,
  name: "LineChart",
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: {
    options: { type: Object },
    chartType: { type: String }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      deep: true,
      handler () {
        this.$data._chart.options = this.options;
        this.updateChart();
      }
    },

    chartType (newVal) {
      this.$data._chart.config.type = newVal;
      this.updateChart()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart () {
      this.$data._chart.update();
    },
  }
}
</script>
```